# Node/Electron exec Rscript misses library paths

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, electron

The basic setup of the project I'm working on (Windows) is an Electron app which communicates with R via R serve. Now everything is working fine except one thing thats been driving me crazy lately.

The problem is that when I use node from cmd (etc. node startR.js) and execute an R script with a command like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var executableR = exec('Rscript startR.R', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

and R code like:

```
library('Rserve')
Rserve()
```

everything goes fine. But, when I try to execute the very same line in the main.js (entrypoint) file for my Electron app, I get the error that the R libraries (i.e. Rserve) can't be found from within R.

I have checked for possible causes for this and I have found out that R library paths differ (.libPaths()) when R is called from cmd node and from electron. Namely, R libs are installed in MyDocuments folder, and R called from cmd node seems to see them properly. On the other hand, the same exec from electron makes R see only the default library path (in program files where R is installed), so it fails to find libraries.

I know that this must be environment issue (like its run from an environment different from the current user), but I'm pretty uncertain what to try. I thought that passing *process.env* to {env: } options for child_process.exec but to no avail.

Comment: did you found your answer, would you have a github project with a working electron solution ?